# Having Issue on Passing Variable into HTML Class Tag

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

Working in WordPress PHP I am trying to pass a value into class tag of an element

> ```
> <div class="element-item"></div>
> ```

to be like

> `<div class="element-item comedy"></div>`

```
$term = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'type' );
echo '<div class="element-item '.$term.'">';
```

the value is pupping out of the class tag and display on the page!

[image]

I checked the source code and it seems that I am passing entire a link to the class tag! 
    Canadian

can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Right, that's because "get_the_term_list" returns an html string of  tags... Those won't work well as class attributes! : )

I suspect what you want is [wp_get_post_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) instead:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'type', array('fields' => 'slugs') ); // array of term slugs
echo '<div class="element-item'.implode(' ', $terms).'">';
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<div class="element-item '.$term.'">';
```

Seems like the ' is closing? Have you tried this?

```
echo '<div class="element-item \'.$term.\'">';
```

or

```
echo "<div class=\"element-item $term\">";
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Comment: Thanks qworx I tried both ways but not working. the first method just added  the `.$term.` like string to the class and second method is behaving as it was